# EF Core 7 Returns Null Child Object When Query Returns Results

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I've created a simple [ASP.NET project using EF Core](https://github.com/rrharvey/efcoredemo) to demonstrate the issue that I'm running into. I expect to see an Author on each Book returned from the /books endpoint. On the first book for each author the Author property is null even though the generated query returns data for every row.

**Data**

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Authors]
(
    [AuthorId] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(100) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Authors PRIMARY KEY (AuthorId)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Books]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [WrittenBy] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Title] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Books PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Books_Author 
        FOREIGN KEY ([WrittenBy]) REFERENCES [Authors] ([AuthorId])
)
GO

INSERT INTO [Authors] ([AuthorId], [Name]) VALUES ('hawking', 'Hawking, Stephen')
INSERT INTO [Authors] ([AuthorId], [Name]) VALUES ('steinbeck', 'Steinbeck, John')
GO

INSERT INTO [Books] ([WrittenBy], [Title]) VALUES ('hawking', 'God Created the Integers')
INSERT INTO [Books] ([WrittenBy], [Title]) VALUES ('hawking', 'The Theory of Everything')
INSERT INTO [Books] ([WrittenBy], [Title]) VALUES ('hawking', 'A Brief History of Time')
INSERT INTO [Books] ([WrittenBy], [Title]) VALUES ('steinbeck', 'The Winter of Our Discontent')
INSERT INTO [Books] ([WrittenBy], [Title]) VALUES ('steinbeck', 'Burning Bright')
INSERT INTO [Books] ([WrittenBy], [Title]) VALUES ('steinbeck', 'A Life in Letters')
GO
```

**Models**

```cs
public class Author
{
    public required string AuthorId { get; set; }
    public required string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required string Title { get; set; }
    public required string WrittenBy { get; set; }
    public required Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class BooksContext : DbContext
{
    public BooksContext(DbContextOptions<BooksContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>(b =>
        {
            b.HasOne(x => x.Author).WithOne().HasForeignKey<Book>(x => x.WrittenBy).IsRequired();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Author>(b =>
        {
            b.HasKey(x => x.AuthorId);
        });
    }
}
```

**App**

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<BooksContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BooksDatabase"))
);

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet(
    "/books",
    async (BooksContext db) =>
    {
        return await db.Books.Include(b => b.Author).ToListAsync();
    }
);

app.Run();
```

Generated query:

```sql
SELECT [b].[Id], [b].[Title], [b].[WrittenBy], [a].[AuthorId], [a].[Name]
FROM [Books] AS [b]
INNER JOIN [Authors] AS [a] ON [b].[WrittenBy] = [a].[AuthorId]
```

Results:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "God Created the Integers",
        "writtenBy": "hawking",
        "author": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "The Theory of Everything",
        "writtenBy": "hawking",
        "author": {
            "authorId": "hawking",
            "name": "Hawking, Stephen"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "A Brief History of Time",
        "writtenBy": "hawking",
        "author": {
            "authorId": "hawking",
            "name": "Hawking, Stephen"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "The Winter of Our Discontent",
        "writtenBy": "steinbeck",
        "author": null
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "Burning Bright",
        "writtenBy": "steinbeck",
        "author": {
            "authorId": "steinbeck",
            "name": "Steinbeck, John"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "A Life in Letters",
        "writtenBy": "steinbeck",
        "author": {
            "authorId": "steinbeck",
            "name": "Steinbeck, John"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: The issue you're facing could be related to the way EFCore handles one-to-one relationships and eager loading. In your `OnModelCreating` method, you've defined a one-to-one relationship between `Book` and `Author`.

This implies that each `Author` can only be associated with one `Book`, which is not the case in your data. You have multiple books by the same author, so the relationship should be one-to-many instead.

Comment: +1, change the `.WithOne()` to `.WithMany()` so that books can share an author reference. EF will attempt to enforce this, though from the data coming back it doesn't seem to be fully enforcing it at read since two of the three books still share an author reference, I'd expect only one would. Either way, you want a many-to-one between book & author as many books share an author.

Comment: That was it. Thank you both. It seems obvious now that you pointed it out but I wasn't seeing it.